# Changing loss function for mgcv gam

Tags: generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model

I am currently using the mgcv GAM-package and would like to experiment with other loss-functions. Specifically I am interested in trying out a loss function, which minizes the relative RMSE rather than the standard RMSE. Does anyone know if that would be possible? As far as I can see the mgcv GAM optimization uses standard log-likelihood minimization, which I guess translates into minimizing the standard quadratic cost. I have however not found other optimization methods that seem to fit my needs.